# How do you save a position of a node in an XML tree to use for later?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an XML tree that I have parsed, and gotten the last added `<url>` node using the `<lastmod>` node. How do I "save" that node position in the tree and use it to get other nodes in the `<url>` it belongs to?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.website.com/</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.website.com/location/</loc>
    <lastmod>2016-10-13T06:03:41Z</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://website.com/image/</image:loc>
      <image:title>Title of Item</image:title>
    </image:image>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.website.com/location/</loc>
    <lastmod>2016-09-15T07:11:22Z</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://website.com/image/</image:loc>
      <image:title>Title of Item</image:title>
    </image:image>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

The first `<url>` tag is the latest addition to the XML document based on the two `<url>` tags. You have to loop through the whole XML document to find that out, though. How do you save the "position" of that XML tag to get the `<image:title>` later on? Here is my code:

```
tree = get_xml_data(line)
        jul_newest = 0.0  # establish a comparison value for the newest addition
        for child in tree:
            if child.tag.endswith("url"):
                for c in child:
                    if c.tag.endswith("lastmod"):
                        xml_date = c.text
                        year = float(xml_date[0:4])
                        month = float(xml_date[5:7])
                        day = float(xml_date[8:10])
                        hour = float(xml_date[11:13])
                        minute = float(xml_date[14:16])
                        second = float(xml_date[17:19])
                        # calculate Julian day number of recent addition
                        jul_day = julian(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
                        if jul_day > jul_newest:
                            nt.set_year(int(year))
                            nt.set_month(int(month))
                            nt.set_day(int(day))
                            nt.set_hour(int(hour))
                            nt.set_minute(int(minute))
                            nt.set_second(int(second))
                            jul_newest = jul_day
                            nt.set_jul(jul_day)
        # find loc of the latest addition
        for child in tree:
            if child.tag.endswith("url"):
                for c in child:
                    if c.tag.endswith("loc"):
                        nt.set_location(c.text)
```

Comment: From what you have posted, it is difficult to tell what `tree` actually is. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code.  Off hand, I'd say the 'position' of the element in the XML needs to be saved when you are parsing the XML, which is the code you have not shown us.

Comment: I suggest you first re-read your question - and fix the places where words were omitted or are in the wrong place. Then, read [mcve] and shorten/change your sample code accordingly.